# Python 3.8: Processing From Memory An Excel File Pulled From Outlook Email

Tags: excel, python-3.x, outlook-2013

I am working on a script that does the following

> 1)    Go through my Outlook inbox
>   2)    Stops at the email that matches my condition
>   3)  Grabs the .XLS Excel file attachment in it (ONLY 1 file)
>   4)  Massage
>   the data in there
>   5)  Save the result file in a folder

The problem is I am trying to have Python process the file from memory 
and I got the following error when reading the file.

```
AttributeError: Item.Read
```

I appreciate any tips here.

```
import win32com.client
import os
import xlrd

from io       import BytesIO 
from datetime import datetime, date
from openpyxl import load_workbook


# Retrieve the email attachment from Outlook.
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")


# Access the Inbox.
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
for message in messages:

    if message.Subject == "XYZ" and message.Senton.date() == date.today():

        attachments = message.Attachments
        a   = attachments.Item(1)


##### Most likely I am missing something between these 2 lines
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=BytesIO(a.read()))
```

Comment: Where do you define the variable "xlrd"?

Comment: ...and what line does the error occur on?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `xlrd` is not a variable here. It's a library and I need it to invoke the `open_workbook` function.  And the error is after the very last line is ran.

Answer (score 1):

I went on a merry internet chase and found this code example in this PDF

https://github.com/python-excel/tutorial/raw/master/python-excel.pdf

```
from mmap import mmap,ACCESS_READ
from xlrd import open_workbook
print open_workbook('simple.xls')
with open('simple.xls','rb') as f:
 print open_workbook(
 file_contents=mmap(f.fileno(),0,access=ACCESS_READ)
 )
aString = open('simple.xls','rb').read()
print open_workbook(file_contents=aString)
```

Comment: I don't want to save and open the file though.  I want to work on the file in memory and then save it as a file.

Comment: To get the file into memory you have to open the file. I'm not a python guy so maybe I'm missing something, but the only time a file _isn't_ loaded into memory is when your computer runs out of memory and has to swap to disk.